# How can I check whether the file have duplicate lines?

Tags: python, duplicates

I need to check whether the file has duplicate lines?

The result should be "true" of "false"

```
with open('user_data_dump') as f:
    seen = set()
    for line in f:
        line_lower = line.lower()
        if line_lower in seen:
            print('true')
        else:
            print('false')
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data please?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print only one time you also need to change how your loop behave: `break` after finding one duplicate and print False only at the end.

```
with open('user_data_dump') as f:
    seen = set()
    for line in f:
        line_lower = line.lower()
        if line_lower in seen:
            print('True')
            break
        else:
            seen.add(line_lower)
    else:
        print('False')
```

Comment: Do you want to print True or False? Or return boolean `True` or `False` ? @lesleyrae

Comment: I want to return True or False

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def func(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        seen = set()
        for line in f:
            line_lower = line.lower()
            if line_lower in seen:
                return True
            else:
                seen.add(line_lower)
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the items you already saw in the set `seen`, and you break the loop the first time you encounter a duplicate value

```
def check_dups():

    #Flag to track if duplicate lines are seen or not
    has_dups = False

    with open('user_data_dump') as f:
        seen = set()
        for line in f:
            line_lower = line.lower()
            #If a duplicate line is encounter, break the loop
            if line_lower in seen:
                has_dups = True
                break
            #Else add the line to set
            else:
                seen.add(line_lower)


    return has_dups
```

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand your comment. `break` is inside the for loop as you can see in the code @lesleyrae Could you please clarify